# print numbers as big as second parameter python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to cut all integers from a list which are lower than a given parameter

```
lis = [23, 52, 91, 75, 3, 68, 17, 88, 105]
lis2 = []

y = int(input("give a minimum number"))

def printbigenough(lis, y):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if lis[i] > y: #checks if i is bigger than the given input
            lis2.append(i) # adds i to the second list (sort of)
    print(lis2)

printbigenough(lis, y)
```

however, instead of returning the numbers which are higher. the program is just printing what positions in the list have higher numbers. does anyone know how to fix this?
also, if this is a poorly constructed code or question i'm sorry... i'm still new at programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you call `lis2.append(i)`. You must call `lis2.append(lis[i])`, like this:

```
lis = [23, 52, 91, 75, 3, 68, 17, 88, 105]
lis2 = []

y = int(input("give a minimum number: "))

def printbigenough(lis, y):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if lis[i] > y: #checks if i is bigger than the given input
            lis2.append(lis[i]) # adds the item to the second list (sort of)
    print(lis2)

printbigenough(lis, y)
```

`i` is the index of the item, not the item

Answer (score 1):

Here is code which returns the list of number greater than the number.

```
lis = [23, 52, 91, 75, 3, 68, 17, 88, 105]
lis2 = []

y = int(input("give a minimum number"))

def printbigenough(lis, y):
    for i in lis:
        if i > y: #checks if i is bigger than the given input
            lis2.append(i) # adds i to the second list (sort of)
    print(lis2)

printbigenough(lis, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
lis = [23, 52, 91, 75, 3, 68, 17, 88, 105]
lis2 = []

y = int(input("give a minimum number"))

def printbigenough(lis, y):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if lis[i] > y: #checks if i is bigger than the given input
            lis2.append(lis[i]) # adds i to the second list (sort of)
    print(lis2)

printbigenough(lis, y)
```

The problem was that you wrote `lis2.append(i)` instead of `lis2.append(lis[i])`